# Help on turning starlight in to voltage

Tags: power-supply, voltage, photodiode

Here’s my issue. I would like to turn bright starlight into voltage. Here’s what I have done.[image]as you can see I have placed a photodiode in a telescope eyepiece tube. I have it below the lens because this is where prime focus is, the place where the scope’s light comes to a point. Here it is on the scope[image] My problem Is that I am not able to generate voltage. The diode I am using is this one. [image]
[image]

The scope is an 8 inch f-10. Would a zero bias diode be better than a reverse bias. If your suggestion involves a diode with more than three pins please advise how wire.

Comment: How are you hooking up the diode?

Comment: One leg to the + and the other leg to the - of the multi-meter to test for voltage.

Comment: Ultimate goal is to get the voltage on an oscilloscope.

Comment: i think that a photo diode does not generate a voltage. its conductive characteristic changes with exposure to light. ... i think that what you want for your application is a solar cell

Comment: What probem are you actually trying to solve? **Why** do you want to turn the light from a star into a voltage?

Comment: @jsotola, the photodiode DOES generate a voltage just like a miniature solar panel. But this is not necessarily the best way to use it. I don't know if it is possible to do what the OP wants, but if it is, for sure it will require an active circuit of some type. Photodiode + transimpedance amplifier, for example. Either in photoconductive mode (reverse biased) or photovoltaic mode (unbiased).

Comment: the best starlight to turn into voltage is that from the brightest star in the sky.

Comment: @Jasen - yeah - the one that's nice & close to us ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are expecting the diode to act like a solar cell. You may simply not have enough light for it to be detectable that way. Try it this way instead.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMGPgb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You may have to play with the resistor value to get what you want. But again, if there is not enough light on the sensor you may need something much more sensitive.

Comment: Wow! very nice, Trevor. Thank you. Can I a rheostat for the resistor and is there a way to tell which lead is which on the photodiode.

Comment: @Lambda yes you could make that adjustable. As for which pin is which, there does appear to be a tag on the case to indicate polarity but without a valid spec sheet I would be guessing what it means. Murphy says whatever I tell you..it would be the other one. However, if you put it in that circuit the wrong way round, with the diode covered, the voltage across it will be low, the right way round in the dark it should be high. It wont hurt the diode as long as the variable resistor is at the big end.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am trying to put this circuit together as we speak. I am using the photodiode that I have shown in this post. Your explanation is so clear and practical. Perfect. One last thought, will this affect the response time.

Comment: @Lambda no it should be the same, if not better. The signal may still be too small for you to really detect with a volt meter though.

Comment: There will be some reverse current, even when the diode is completely dark. So a calibration step should be used.

Comment: @Trevor When I connect like the schematic I get 6.60 volts in the dark, but when I expose it to light the voltage drops. Is this the way it should be. It does seem to be more sensitive but in the reverse.

Comment: @Lambda yes, the diode will be less resistance when lit. If you need it the other way swap them around.

Comment: @Trevor When I switch the diode connection the voltage drops to less than a volt and it is not very sensitive. The way that gives me 6 plus volts is much more sensitive. I guess I will just see a change in voltage rather than an increase in voltage. If it drops from 6.6 to 6.4 is that saying the light input was 0.2 volts

Comment: @Trevor I have also noticed that when I hold it for a while it heats up and reacts differently. Thanks for your help. I'll try it on a star tonight and see it I get a drop in voltage.

Answer (score 3):

I think that in order to maximize sensitivity you are going to need to use an amplifier. There are two basic modes of operation: photovoltaic mode and photoconductive mode.

In photovoltaic mode, when using a transimpedance amplifier, the voltage across the diode is held at zero volts, and the amplifier converts the diode output current to voltage. Zero light means zero current and zero voltage. There should be no dark current.

In photoconductive mode, the diode is reverse biased. This mode also uses a transimpedance amplifier to convert current to voltage. In this mode, a certain amount of reverse leakage current will be present, and thus must be calibrated out of the measurement.

Unless you can find a good reference, you may need to try both modes. Here is an image from thorlabs (my main source of information):

[image: photodiode active circuit]

Note in the diagram that the basic connection is the same for the two modes. It is just a question of whether the anode is connected to GND or to a negative bias voltage.

I found the image here:
https://www.thorlabs.com/tutorials.cfm?tabID=31760

Answer (score 0):

### For power?

There is not a lot of energy in starlight, even if focused. There are just not that many photons striking *Earth* from a distant star... let alone the aperture of your telescope!

Silicon devices are not sensitive enough to create any usable power this way (power generated less than leakage).

### For signal?

Just trying to detect the light or measure it? If you can't get enough signal with silicon diodes or transistors, you have to upgrade to scientist level ;-)

This is a Photomultiplier Tube (PMT):

[image]

Wikipedia's description is correct, but not very helpful:

> Photomultiplier Tubes. A photomultiplier tube, useful for light
>   detection of very weak signals, is a photoemissive device in which the
>   absorption of a photon results in the emission of an electron. These
>   detectors work by amplifying the electrons generated by a photocathode
>   exposed to a photon flux.

The way they work is that you create a very strong electric field inside the tube. When a photon enters the tube it is accelerated rapidly by the strong field gaining a lot of energy in the process. It then collides with a metal plate at high speed (energy). When this happens it knocks some electrons off the metal plate. These electrons are also accelerated rapidly by the field.

By arranging the internals of the tube so that multiple collisions occur you can make the signal very strong as each collision creates more free electrons, which after colliding with the next plate, will each create more free electrons... and so on until you reach the end where you measure the significant number of collisions as voltage.

Comment: Depends how big the telescope is....

Comment: But I do agree, a stock photodiode may not be sensitive enough.

Comment: Thank for the response. "Just trying to detect the light or measure it?" I will be measuring it.

Answer (score 0):

Such a feeble light source as starlight may not be measurable by a photodiode. *Diode leakage current* (or dark current) will be the most significant competitor of tiny starlight current. Diode leakage current is highly dependent on diode temperature - a cold diode has less leakage.
To see if your photodiode is starlight-capable, a circuit is required that yields an output affected by diode dark current. The digital voltmeter (VM1) in the following circuit should have 10 Megohm input resistance, and a sensitive scale of 200 mV, with a display that would show 199 mV as `199.9`. That last digit increments every 100 microvolts. When this voltmeter is placed in series with a reverse-biased photodiode, it converts to \$ 100/10 \$ picoamps resolution. That may be sensitive enough to be affected by dark current. Such digital voltmeters are quite common.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFPqMp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>